# How to set document icon instead of application icon in Windows?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, windows-explorer, icons, sublime-text

If I have a file extension associated with an application, such as xml files with Sublime Text 3 or html files with Chrome, the icons in Windows explorer are using the "application" icon for the document icon.

[image]

I seem to remember there's a way to pick the icon from the app to actually use in Explorer.  I'd rather have what Sublime uses for "document" than a bunch of application icons for all my files.

I'm on Windows 8.1 Pro, but I'm more of a Mac person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually change the icon for a file type [through the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427.aspx), but it’s easier and safer to do it with a program like [FileTypesManager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html):

[image: Screenshot of FileTypesManager’s Edit-File-Type dialog]

Not all programs provide a document icon, but you can use any `.ico`, `.dll`, `.exe` or icon library (`.icl`) file, so you don’t have to be limited to just the program’s files.

For Chrome, you could try using the gold logo below. You can also [search for a user-made icon](http://www.google.com/search?q=chrome%20html%20icon&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:i) (like [this](http://www.neowin.net/forum/uploads/post-99705-1220752098.png) or [this](http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/306/4/4/google_chrome_internet_shortcut_icon_by_charlesmilette-d6sq1sl.png) or [this](http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/306/1/5/google_chrome_internet_shortcut_icon_old_version_by_charlesmilette-d6sqv8g.png)). Likewise [for XML files](http://www.google.com/search?q=xml%20file%20icon&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:i). (Don’t forget to [convert](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert+png+to+ico) non-`.ico` files.)

[image: Chrome’s gold logo]

Comment: Thanks.  It would seem that neither Chrome nor ST supply document icons in their EXE or any DLLs I can find.

Comment: Then you’re free to use whatever you want like the ones I linked to or *anything*, even [kittens](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/cats) and [ponies](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/subcultures/my-little-pony-friendship-is-magic).